# In GCP, can I prevent deletion of a VM, created by me, by another user?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam

In a given GCP project, all team members have access to create and delete VMs. We need a solution to avoid one member deleting a VM created by another member. How can we restrict members from accidentally deleting each other's VMs within a project?

Comment: In addition to Martin's answer, you can set "Enable deletion protection" on a VM. This will not prevent some with the correct IAM role from disabling the flag but will prevent accidental VM deletion: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preventing-accidental-vm-deletion

Comment: @John, thank you. Yes, that will help but not completely resolve the issue.

Comment: If someone has the correct IAM roles, there is nothing you can do. They can delete resources. If the "Enable deletion flag" is enabled and a user then removes the flag and then deletes the VM, which are separate steps, that was not an accident. That was deliberate. Your question states **from accidentally deleting**. If you do not trust those users, the solution is simple, don't give them GUI or CLI access. Security is easy to implement.

Comment: @JohnHanley See my alternate answer; this prevents one user from interfering with another one's VM; the down-side is just, that they cannot spin up new VM alike that. It's still an easy way to apply fine-grained IAM permissions in batch mode.

Answer (score 1):

Such fine-grained permissions can be defined by [IAM policies for Compute Engine resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access#resource-policies):

> Grant users access to a specific subset of resources.
> Suppose Alice should manage a subset of instances in a project. With instance-level IAM policies, you grant her the `compute.instanceAdmin.v1` role **on only those instances**. If you granted Alice the same role on the project, then she would have permission to modify all instances in the project.

---

Cloud IAM doesn't directly support scripting, but the [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) CLI can be automated.

When a text file called `mappings.txt` provides the mappings:

```
instance-1 user1@acme.com
instance-2 user2@acme.com
instance-3 user3@acme.com
```

Then one can process that config file with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROJECT_ID=$(gcloud config get-value project)

while read LINE; do

    INSTANCE=${LINE% *}
    USER=${LINE#* }

    # update project policy
    gcloud projects remove-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID \
        --member="user:${USER}" \
        --role="roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1"

    # update instance policy
    gcloud compute instances add-iam-policy-binding $INSTANCE \
        --member="user:${USER}" \
        --role="roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1"

done < ./mappings.txt
```

Removing `roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1` also prevents them from creating new instances, but there seems to be no other way to prevent them from administering another user's instance. This loop might well be suitable to setup instances for a whole team or classroom - and it could create them, as well. With many users and instances, "combing through" is the most effective.

---

Or when wanting to apply `--deletion-protection` to all instances of the current project:

```
#!/bin/bash
for INSTANCE in `gcloud compute instances list --format="value(name)"`; do
    gcloud compute instances update $INSTANCE \
        --deletion-protection 
done
```

---

There would also be the possibility, to clone `roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1` as a custom role and then taking away all of the delete permissions (which not only do exist for VM instances):

```
gcloud iam roles describe roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1 | grep delete
gcloud iam roles describe roles/compute.admin | grep delete
```

I'd rather ask, if `roles/compute.admin` or `roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1` is even required for what they're doing? It's usually enough, when there's someone or a small team responsible for that; IAM also supports setting up groups, which makes this easier to handle.